# Set in a bash script vs function parameter

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

I am changing a bash script which has a structure as such:

```
#somewhere in the code
sim_counts=#... some value
function_name()
{
    set $sim_counts
    for hostname in $linux_hostnames; do
        if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then # if sim_counts equal 0
            shift  # jump forward in sim_counts
            continue 
        fi
    # ... more code
    shift
    done
}
```

Then it is called in the script:

```
function_name
```

---

I want to introduce a parameter to this function:

```
#somewhere in the code
sim_counts=#... some value
function_name()
{
    ip=$1
    set $sim_counts
    for hostname in $linux_hostnames; do
        if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then # if sim_counts equal 0
            shift  # jump forward in sim_counts
            continue 
        fi
    # ... more code
    shift
    done
}
```

And call the function in following way:

```
function_name 10.255.192.123
```

What should I do to avoid `$1` conflict of function parameter and the other value from `set` command ?

Comment: What does `$sim_counts` represent?

Comment: @JonahBishop It is a value of processes launched on a particular machine.

Comment: Since you saved the function's parameter to `ip` before calling `set`, I'm not sure you have a real conflict. That said, why do you need to use `set` here? Can't you just use `sim_counts` the way you are using `$1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correctly reading the [set builtin page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) in the Bash Reference Manual, I believe the code as you have written it will just work. Quoting from that page:

> The remaining N arguments are positional parameters and are assigned, in order, to $1, $2, … $N. The special parameter # is set to N.

In essence, any pre-existing values for the positional variables will be blown away. The first sentence on that manual page is also interesting:

> This builtin is so complicated that it deserves its own section.

In short, I think your code should simply work as expected. You've saved the initial value of `$1` (from the function call) into a temporary variable; as long as you refer to `$ip` for that specific value, you should be good. In my own test script, it seems that `$1` gets blown away as I expect it should.

Comment: You are right. `$ip` correct, `$1` assigned to `$sim_counts`. Thanks.